# Weird character appears when execute selected codes in Visual Studio 2013 F# Interactive

Tags: visual-studio, f#

Below code is try to use gnuplot to plot a chart. When i run it in Visual Studio 2013 F# Interactive, the error in below image is shown. However when i copy the codes to FSI in cmd/LinqPad, the gnuplot is shown correctly. Does anybody know why that happens? I also tried to use monostudio, the same issue with visual studio.

```
open System
open System.Diagnostics

let gp =  
  new ProcessStartInfo
    (FileName = "gnuplot", UseShellExecute = false, 
     CreateNoWindow = true, RedirectStandardInput = true) 
  |> Process.Start

// Draw graph of two simple functions
gp.StandardInput.WriteLine "plot sin(x) + sin(3*x), -x"
```

[image: error image]

11/23/2015 updated:
Bad news:
Manually re-typed the string again, but it doesn't work. 
Save that as a script & run with fsi, the chart is showing.

Good news:
Funplot library is working.

Comment: I'm not sure what's going on, but if you're using gnuplot, check out this project: http://fsprojects.github.io/FnuPlot/ (it is very basic and incomplete, but you might find it useful!)

Comment: @TomasPetricek I'm confused too, calling `gp.StandardInput.WriteLine "plot sin(x) + sin(3*x), -x"` seems to work every time you do it other than the first.

Comment: It could be an invisible character.  Did you copy-paste that into your code?  If so then you could try manually re-typing that string.

Comment: Thanks guys, TomasPetricek, TheInnerLight, mydogisbox. Can't figure out why, switch to use funplot.